# Переход с SqliteOpenhelper на Room

Tags: android, android-room

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать переход с SQLiteOpenHelper на Room? Чисто с нуля используя Room написать приложение не проблема, но есть существующий проект, и хотелось бы его перевести на Room.

Объекты Entity, Dao, Database создам, а дальше?

P.S. таблицы и данные в них не изменяются, а только нужно сделать переход на room.

Получаю ошибку в коде

```
@Database(entities = {City.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CityDao cityDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "city.db";

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

> Process: ru.natasha.mycity, PID: 32068 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ru.natasha.mycity/ru.natasha.mycity.ui.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
>   ru.natasha.mycity.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not
>   exist at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
>   ru.natasha.mycity.database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not
>   exist at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
>   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:667) at
>   ru.natasha.mycity.database.AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(AppDatabase.java:24)
>   at ru.natasha.mycity.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Сейчас такая ошибка

> Expected: TableInfo{name='city', columns={image=Column{name='image',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   filename=Column{name='filename', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, author=Column{name='author',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   source=Column{name='source', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false,
>   primaryKeyPosition=0}, text=Column{name='text', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   category=Column{name='category', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, favorite=Column{name='favorite',
>   type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}},
>   foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>
> Found: TableInfo{name='city', columns={image=Column{name='image',
>   type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   filename=Column{name='filename', type='Text', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, author=Column{name='author',
>   type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   source=Column{name='source', type='Text', affinity='2', notNull=false,
>   primaryKeyPosition=0}, text=Column{name='text', type='Text',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, title=Column{name='title', type='Text',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   category=Column{name='category', type='Text', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, favorite=Column{name='favorite',
>   type='Integer', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}},
>   foreignKeys=[], indices=[]} at
>   ru.natasha.mycity.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1.validateMigration(AppDatabase_Impl.java:80)

В AppDatabase такой код

```
@Database(entities = {City.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CityDao cityDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "city.db";

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

        }
    };

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: room упрощает создания базы данных. Вам нужно только переписать, укав имя базы и поля.

Comment: Это да, но если просто я перепишу приложение используя Room и запущу его на устройстве где это же приложение с SqliteOpenHelper использовалось, то приложение вылетает

Comment: Надо смотреть с какой ошибкой вылетает. Может дело в версии - тогда надо с миграциями повозиться. А может там типы не так получились. В общем - без сообщений об ошибке ничего сказать не выйдет.

Comment: Сейчас скину. Но мне кажется нужно миграцию делать.

Comment: И еще выходит такая ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number. Затем подняла версию БД и вышло такое сообщение  java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.

Comment: Ну, видимо да - надо миграцию написать. В ней, видимо, надо создать все таблицы, что есть в старой БД и перенести туда все данные. Ну или смотреть можно ли Room-у указать что БД уже есть. Возможно потребуется в папку shemas файл пихнуть с описанием БД. Он, вроде, должен даже генериться... В общем как-то так, наверное)

Comment: Вроде написала миграцию по одной статье, вопрос обновила. Как я понимаю Expected и Found вроде одинаковые, но не могу понять в чем пробелма

Comment: Вам же база выдает, сто структура стала другой. Просто сделали ошибку. Я даже мельком видел, гдет вконце что у вас параметры разные по стектрейсу. Можете сразу написать миграцию, всеравно будет необходима

Comment: Уже получилось!